# Is there anyway to use the inputStream after it closed in java?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, java-io

Need to use the inputStream of a file in various methods but I used the inputStream in try-with-resources so that it results in stream is closed error. Is there anyway to use the inputStream to another method after it closed in java ?

Comment: No, you cannot reopen a stream after it is closed.  It is unclear why or how you are trying to reuse the InputStream so it is hard to suggest a strategy for how you can share one.

Comment: You can re-read an input stream, but not after it's *closed*

Comment: No [tag:java-stream] here, or [tag:arrays] either.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to use the `InputStream` after it is closed in Java, this is the purpose of closed.
If you want to keep a usable `InputStream` outside of your `try{}` block, you should not use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) method, and just close it in a `catch` block.
But then you need to think about what will happen if you get an exception outside of the `try` block.

If the same resource has to be used by multiple methods and you want to make sure it is closed if you get any kind of error, you should have a `try{}` block that encapsulates all the methods that follow and closes your resources.